# How to pluck then concatenate the last two in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

Im not getting the expected results. [Pluck](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) returns an array so why `.last` does not work?

Here's an example without actual example data:

```rb
Model.all.map { |obj| {name: obj.name, accounts: obj.accounts.pluck(:id, :code, :name) }

# Returns:
[
  {name: "Stock", accounts: ["12345", "090", "Imports 2%"], [...] },
  {...}
],
[...]
```

**What I'm actually doing:**

```rb
Model.all.map { |obj| {name: obj.name, accounts: obj.accounts.pluck(:id, :code, :name).last(2).join('-') }

# Returns

[
  {name: "Stock", accounts: "12345-090-Imports 2%"},
  {...}
],
[...]
```

**I expect:**

```rb
[
  {name: "Stock", accounts: ["12345", "090-Imports 2%"], [...]},
  {...}
],
[...]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `pluck` returns an array of arrays, so you are essentially calling `join` on the array of arrays (accounts), rather than on the individual attributes (code and name).

Comment: So basically I need to go "deeper"?

Comment: Yes, definitely. `pluck...last(2)` gives you something like `[[333, 'code1', 'name1'], [777, 'code2', 'name2']]`

Comment: Thanks! I got it but I'll accept an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Model.all.map do |obj| 
  accounts = obj.accounts.pluck(:id, :code, :name).map { |id, code, name| [id, "#{code}-#{name}"] }
  {
    name: obj.name, 
    accounts: accounts
  }
end
```

but it should be optimized

Answer (score 1):

Replace `pluck(:id, :code, :name).last(2).join('-')` with `last(2).pluck(:id, :code, :name).join('-') }`

Comment: `g.accounts.last(2).pluck(:id, :code, :name).join('-')` gives same result, sorry. I believe I need `pluck` first?

Comment: @Sylar No, you don't. This is just wrong answer. See Arjan's one.